# mplfinance plot doesn't show time values correctly

Tags: python, mplfinance

My first question on Stackoverflow. Hope the format satisfies Stackoverflow's requirement.

I'm learning Python and using "mplfinance" to plot 5-minute stock price, but the time on the x-axes is not right. My test code is as below. The time axes of the plot is "*18:05, 18:30, 18:55, 19:20, 19:45, 20:10, 20:35*" which don't show in the data file at all. I extracted 3 days data up to Dec 4 (or Dec 5), 2020 from Yahoo and plotted the last 35 points after some simple processing. (if you run the program at a different day, the time axis will be different)

Thank you for any help and enlightenment!

```
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf

def plot_5min_chart():
        # 5-minute data
        mdata = yf.download('DDD', period='3d', interval='5m')
        mdata = pd.DataFrame(mdata)
        mdata['10ma'] = mdata['Close'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=0).mean()
        mdata['20ma'] = mdata['Close'].rolling(window=20, min_periods=0).mean()
        mdata['50ma'] = mdata['Close'].rolling(window=50, min_periods=0).mean()
        mdata.dropna(inplace=True)
        mdata.to_csv('test_5minute.csv')

        # plot 5-minute chart
        mpf.figure()
        ntl2 = 35
        kwargs = dict(type='candle', volume=True, figratio=(8,5),
                      figscale=0.85, num_panels=3, panel_ratios=(6,2,2))
        ap2 = [
            mpf.make_addplot(mdata['10ma'].tail(ntl2), width=2, linestyle='-', color='lime', panel=0),
            mpf.make_addplot(mdata['20ma'].tail(ntl2), width=2, linestyle='--', color='c', panel=0),
            mpf.make_addplot(mdata['50ma'].tail(ntl2), width=2, linestyle='-', color='orange', panel=0),
        ]
        titlem = '5-minute chart'
        mpf.plot(mdata.tail(ntl2),**kwargs, addplot=ap2, style='charles', title=titlem,
                 savefig=dict(fname='5minutechart.png', dpi=800, pad_inches=8)
                 )

plot_5min_chart()
```

[test 5-minute chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/csqa4.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the same as a known-bug in mplfinance, reported here: https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/236

The fix for this is released now.  To get the newest code:
**`pip install --upgrade mplfinance`**

If anyone was depending on the old behavior (that used time zone info, when present, in the datetime index, to convert to UTC) they can access that old behavior by setting **kwarg `tz_localize=False`** when calling `mpf.plot()`.

The new behavior is to ignore tzinfo in the datetime index and always plot according to the local time in the datetime index.

Comment: Thank you very much, Daniel! That solves the problem.